# Can't bind value to button on release in Kivy python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I wanted to save output of print to value so I can use it later.
I have no idea where to go with it

```
    #btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: print(btn.text))
```

full code:

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp


# create a dropdown with 10 buttons
dropdown = DropDown()
for index in range(1, 13):
    # When adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually
    # (disabling the size_hint_y) so the dropdown can calculate
    # the area it needs.

    btn = Button(text='%d moth' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
    # for each button, attach a callback that will call the select() method
    # on the dropdown. We'll pass the text of the button as the data of the
    # selection.
    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))

    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: print(btn.text))

    # then add the button inside the dropdown
    dropdown.add_widget(btn)
# create a big main button
mainbutton = Button(text='How many months ago', size_hint=(None, None))

# show the dropdown menu when the main button is released
# note: all the bind() calls pass the instance of the caller (here, the
# mainbutton instance) as the first argument of the callback (here,
# dropdown.open.).
mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
# one last thing, listen for the selection in the dropdown list and
# assign the data to the button text.
dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
print(value)
runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

I want to save number that user choose

Answer (score 0):

This may get you closer to what you want.  I don't know if this is your whole application or if you pared down to minimal function just to post here.

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from functools import partial

# create a dropdown with 10 buttons
dropdown = DropDown()
global_selection = ""
for index in range(1, 13):
    # When adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually
    # (disabling the size_hint_y) so the dropdown can calculate
    # the area it needs.

    btn = Button(text='%d moth' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
    # for each button, attach a callback that will call the select() method
    # on the dropdown. We'll pass the text of the button as the data of the
    # selection.
    def new_func(self, my_button):
        global_selection = my_button.text
        print(f"The button selected was {global_selection}")

    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
    btn.bind(on_release=partial(new_func, btn))

    # then add the button inside the dropdown
    dropdown.add_widget(btn)
# create a big main button
mainbutton = Button(text='How many months ago', size_hint=(None, None))

# show the dropdown menu when the main button is released
# note: all the bind() calls pass the instance of the caller (here, the
# mainbutton instance) as the first argument of the callback (here,
# dropdown.open.).
mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
# one last thing, listen for the selection in the dropdown list and
# assign the data to the button text.
dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

Comment: I'm very thankful for your response but it didn't solve my problem. I wrote code that gives me chosen number in command line too:    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: print(btn.text)) But i still can't access to chosen number in code, I want program that after I chose number from dropdown adds 10 and chosen number and prints out result